# More people appearing on Game Center leaderboard than should be

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have an iOS game on the App Store that includes four Game Center leaderboards. One of them is free, but the three others are behind an in-app purchase. However, I have about double the amount of people on the paid leaderboards than iTunes Connect says have bought the app. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: They may use jailbroken devices and bypass the IAP.

Comment: @the4kman that many users? If it were just one or two I'd say that makes sense, but over half of them? Is it in any way possible that iTunes Connect made a mistake and reported too few purchases?